# Алгоритм реализации z-index'а в 2d игре

Tags: c++, 2d, z-index, sfml

Здравствуйте!

Необходимо реализовать z-index в 2D игре. Игра работает на **SFML2** + самописные библиотеки.

В самой SFML z-index'а нет. Как можно реализовать его? Вектор со спрайтами, который сортируется по z-index'у не подходить, постоянно нужно добавлять и  убирать спрайты, производительность падает.

Подскажите алгоритм, пожалуйста! Так же буду рад ссылкам на статьи.

Спасибо!

Comment: Один из вариантов - при отрисовке спрайта, не сразу его рисовать, а добавлять в `std::priority_queue`, для которой задать компаратор, сравнивающий координаты. После пройти по этой очереди и выполнить отрисовку.

Comment: Насколько быстро это может работать? Мне кажется, создавать `std::priority_queue` 60 раз в секунду не очень удачное решение...

Comment: Десятки тысяч спрайтов без каких либо задержек на телефоне Galaxy S3. https://github.com/vladimirgamalian/neopedersia/blob/master/src/WorldPainterImpl.h

Comment: Само создание объекта `priority_queue` не требует больших ресурсов. Добавление с сортировкой выполняется очень быстро.

Comment: Хм, спасибо, посмотрю в эту сторону.

Comment: Работает шикарно! Спасибо огромное! Это то, что мне нужно!